# How to tell if Image.FromStream is complete

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, gdi+, gdi

i have the following code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
var response = request.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (stream != null) {
    Image newImage = Image.FromStream(stream, true);
    pic.Thumb = newImage.ImageToByteArray();
}
```

What happens if the read times out?  Or the connection is aborted mid-download?

The docs say that it will throw an `ArgumentException` if it's not a valid format or is null, but I have no idea if it will throw that exception if the image is only partially downloaded.

Unfortunately, I can't rely on the ContentLength header to tell me the proper size of the file, because the server lies and gives a larger content length than the file actually is.  So my hope is that Image.FromStream will be able to tell if the image is complete or not.

Can anyone provide some insight here?

Note: ImageToByteArray is just an extension method that uses a memory stream to convert the `Image` to a `byte[]`

UPDATE:

According to Darin, then an ExternalException gets thrown when you try to save the image.  However, my own testing in which I truncated an image file shows that `FromStream` does in fact throw an ArgumentException if the image is not the correct number of bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens if the read times out?

An exception will be thrown before entering the `if` condition.

> Or the connection is aborted?

An exception will be thrown before entering the `if` condition.

> but I have no idea if it will throw that exception if the image is only partially downloaded.

An image cannot be partially downloaded. The `GetResponseStream` is a blocking method meaning that either you get everything, or an exception (or of course in your case you could also get an exception if what you fetched is not an image but some HTML page which will happen when you try to instantiate the Image GDI+ object).

As a side note, to avoid leaking, you probably also want to wrap this `Image` disposable resource into a `using` statement.

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  What happens if the server simply does not send a complete image?  (Let's say they are having load issues and get timeouts in their backend, and simply send a partial image, but otherwise the connection is normal)

Comment: @Mystere Man, I don't understand. You mean the server sending a byte array which is an invalid image, like the remote resource hosting a corrupt image? If yes, then you will get an `ArgumentException` when you try to load this stream into the Image GDI+ object (`Image.FromStream` method).

Comment: I mean, I am unsure if the Image class will detect a partial image as invalid or not and throw the ArgumentException.

Comment: @Mystere Man, Image.FromStream will throw an `ArgumentException` if the stream contains an invalid image that it cannot handle as explained in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx.

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation.  I'm asking if the Image class considers partial images invalid.  I assume the image formats include length headers, but does the Image class validate that the actual data is of the appropriate length.

Comment: @Mystere Man, you will get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.` but not when calling the `Image.FromStream` method but when you try to do something with this image, like for example save it to a file.

Comment: That's what I needed to know.  You are a fount of knowledge Darin ;)